# Start exe and parse argument via a batch file

Tags: batch-file, exe

Following script in VB to open an exe and parse in an argument works ok.

```
    strProgramName = "C:\Documents\Test\Imp\imp.exe"
strArgument = " -NENTRY" 

Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """ " & strArgument, vbNormalFocus)
```

Trying to replace this using a batch file where i can open an exe and parse a parameter in. -NENTRY should open a window on the exe once its ran, however its not working in my exe. Below is my current script: it opens the exe but does not open the new window (which works in the VB script)

```
start /b "" "C:\Documents\Test\Imp\imp.exe" -NENTRY
```

What am I missing?

Comment: remove `/b` and it will... as `/b` is to Start application without creating a new window.

Comment: Doesnt work still - it opens the .exe, but does not recognise the -NENTRY argument. However the VB script did recognise it.

Comment: is the `exe` cmdline based? did it execute the exe with parameters when you had `/b`?

Comment: It did not execute when I had /b either. Is it related to the fact im calling 'Shell' in VB but not on the batch file. Im guessing its not cmdline based but dont 100% know

Comment: what happens if you only do, without start `"C:\Documents\Test\Imp\imp.exe" -NENTRY`

Comment: It starts the exe, but again does not take the argument (-.NENTRY)

Comment: that is strange... You could try in cmd.exe to `cd` to `C:\Documents\Test\Imp` then simply run `imp.exe -NENTRY` and tell me what happens?

Comment: It does the same thing - opens the .exe, but ignores the argument -NENTRY

Comment: However, this does work in VB script in an excel file ? Code used in question